# After publishing the url on public domain, I can see the IBM HTTP Server's default page but not the application

Tags: httpd.conf, ibmhttpserver

The public url that we are trying to access is hitting the url https://hostname.domain:port/ of the IBM HTTP Server
We are using Amazon cloud. There is an ELB and WAF also involved. (But this is not the issue)

I need to change the request url to https://hostname.domainname:port/some_path_file_directory/XYZ.jsp
Also, i need to do this internally. (Without showing the rewriting)

This i need to do in the httpd.conf file. I tried many scenarios but still not able to find the solution for it. I have tried rewrite but I am not sure where exactly to place it or how exactly to use it.

Request you all to kindly help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: For external redirection you can try covener suggestion, for "default" page you have tu use DirectoryIndex directive.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just append something like this to your virtualhost (or append to  httpd.conf if no virtualhosts defined)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule ^/$ /whatever/foo.jsp [PT]
```

Comment: Hi Covener - Thanks for the prompt reply. I have tried this but this redirect affects the public url and an error message is seen stating - "You need to be in so_and_so_domain to access the application."